# Media upload to twitter without third party library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to post multiple images to twitter using the media/upload so that I can tweet using multiple images. but unable to do. So, I get an unauthorized 401 error. I can not use any third party library

```
var oauth_token = "***"; //"insert here...";
var oauth_token_secret = "***"; //"insert here...";
var oauth_consumer_key = "***";// = "insert here...";
var oauth_consumer_secret = "***";// = "insert here...";

// oauth implementation details
var oauth_version = "1.0";
var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

// unique request details
var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
- new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();


var resource_url = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json";

// create oauth signature
var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_nonce,
oauth_signature_method,
oauth_timestamp,
oauth_token,
oauth_version//,
//Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name)
);

baseString = string.Concat("POST&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

string oauth_signature;
using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
{
  oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                   hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
}

// create the request header
var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
"oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
"oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
"oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
);


// make the request

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\desert.jpg");
var postBody = "media=" + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
resource_url += "?" + postBody;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
// return responseData;
}
catch (Exception ed)
{
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved the issue by using Juan María Hernández's tinytwitter class with the changes that I need

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace tweetmedia.Models
{
public class OAuthInfo
{
    public string ConsumerKey { get; set; }
    public string ConsumerSecret { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string AccessSecret { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TinyTwitter
{
    private readonly OAuthInfo oauth;

    public TinyTwitter(OAuthInfo oauth)
    {
        this.oauth = oauth;
    }

    public string UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
        string web = new RequestBuilder(oauth, "POST", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
            .AddParameter("status", message)
            .Execute();
        return web;
    }
    public string UpdateStatuswithmedia(string message, string media)
    {
        string web = new RequestBuilder(oauth, "POST", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")
            .AddParameter("status", message)
            .AddParameter("media_ids", media)
            .Execute();
        return web;
    }
    public string UpdateMedia(string message)
    {
        string web = new RequestBuilder(oauth, "POST", "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json")
            .AddParameter("media", message)
            .Execute();
        return web;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tweet> GetHomeTimeline(long? sinceId = null, int? count = 20)
    {
        return GetTimeline("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json", sinceId, count);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tweet> GetMentions(long? sinceId = null, int? count = 20)
    {
        return GetTimeline("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions.json", sinceId, count);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tweet> GetUserTimeline(long? sinceId = null, int? count = 20)
    {
        return GetTimeline("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", sinceId, count);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Tweet> GetTimeline(string url, long? sinceId, int? count)
    {
        var builder = new RequestBuilder(oauth, "GET", url);

        if (sinceId.HasValue)
            builder.AddParameter("since_id", sinceId.Value.ToString());

        if (count.HasValue)
            builder.AddParameter("count", count.Value.ToString());

        string content;
        var response = builder.Execute(out content);

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var tweets = (object[])serializer.DeserializeObject(content);

        return tweets.Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>().Select(tweet =>
        {
            var user = ((Dictionary<string, object>)tweet["user"]);
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(tweet["created_at"].ToString(),
                "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zz00 yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToLocalTime();
            return new Tweet
            {
                Id = (long)tweet["id"],
                CreatedAt =
                    date,
                Text = (string)tweet["text"],
                UserName = (string)user["name"],
                ScreenName = (string)user["screen_name"]
            };
        }).ToArray();
    }

    #region RequestBuilder

    public class RequestBuilder
    {
        private const string VERSION = "1.0";
        private const string SIGNATURE_METHOD = "HMAC-SHA1";

        private readonly OAuthInfo oauth;
        private readonly string method;
        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> customParameters;
        private readonly string url;

        public RequestBuilder(OAuthInfo oauth, string method, string url)
        {
            this.oauth = oauth;
            this.method = method;
            this.url = url;
            customParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public RequestBuilder AddParameter(string name, string value)
        {
            customParameters.Add(name, value.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986());
            return this;
        }

        public string Execute()
        {
            string content;
            Execute(out content);
            return content;
        }

        public WebResponse Execute(out string content)
        {
            try
            {
                var timespan = GetTimestamp();
                var nonce = CreateNonce();

                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>(customParameters);
                AddOAuthParameters(parameters, timespan, nonce);

                var signature = GenerateSignature(parameters);
                var headerValue = GenerateAuthorizationHeaderValue(parameters, signature);

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(GetRequestUrl());
                request.Method = method;
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", headerValue);

                WriteRequestBody(request);

                // It looks like a bug in HttpWebRequest. It throws random TimeoutExceptions
                // after some requests. Abort the request seems to work. More info: 
                // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252762/getrequeststream-throws-timeout-exception-randomly

                var response = request.GetResponse();

                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                request.Abort();

                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                content = "";
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void WriteRequestBody(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            if (method == "GET")
                return;

            var requestBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetCustomParametersString());
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                stream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
        }

        private string GetRequestUrl()
        {
            if (method != "GET" || customParameters.Count == 0)
                return url;

            return string.Format("{0}?{1}", url, GetCustomParametersString());
        }

        private string GetCustomParametersString()
        {
            return customParameters.Select(x => string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value)).Join("&");
        }

        private string GenerateAuthorizationHeaderValue(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters, string signature)
        {
            return new StringBuilder("OAuth ")
                .Append(parameters.Concat(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_signature", signature))
                            .Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("oauth_"))
                            .Select(x => string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", x.Key, x.Value.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986()))
                            .Join(","))
                .ToString();
        }

        private string GenerateSignature(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
        {
            var dataToSign = new StringBuilder()
                .Append(method).Append("&")
                .Append(url.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986()).Append("&")
                .Append(parameters
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                            .Select(x => string.Format("{0}={1}", x.Key, x.Value))
                            .Join("&")
                            .EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986());

            var signatureKey = string.Format("{0}&{1}", oauth.ConsumerSecret.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(), oauth.AccessSecret.EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986());
            var sha1 = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureKey));

            var signatureBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSign.ToString()));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
        }

        private void AddOAuthParameters(IDictionary<string, string> parameters, string timestamp, string nonce)
        {
            parameters.Add("oauth_version", VERSION);
            parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth.ConsumerKey);
            parameters.Add("oauth_nonce", nonce);
            parameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", SIGNATURE_METHOD);
            parameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", timestamp);
            parameters.Add("oauth_token", oauth.AccessToken);
        }

        private static string GetTimestamp()
        {
            return ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        }

        private static string CreateNonce()
        {
            return new Random().Next(0x0000000, 0x7fffffff).ToString("X8");
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class TinyTwitterHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, items.ToArray());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T value)
    {
        return items.Concat(new[] { value });
    }

    public static string EncodeRFC3986(this string value)
    {
        // From Twitterizer http://www.twitterizer.net/

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return string.Empty;

        var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(value);

        return Regex
            .Replace(encoded, "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper())
            .Replace("(", "%28")
            .Replace(")", "%29")
            .Replace("$", "%24")
            .Replace("!", "%21")
            .Replace("*", "%2A")
            .Replace("'", "%27")
            .Replace("%7E", "~");
    }

    public static string EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(this string value)
    {
        StringBuilder escaped = new StringBuilder();

        string validChars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._~";

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (validChars.Contains(c.ToString()))
            {
                escaped.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                escaped.Append("%" + Convert.ToByte(c).ToString("x2").ToUpper());
            }
        }

        // Return the fully-RFC3986-escaped string.
        return escaped.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

I am using this method to upload the image with post

```
public string PostToTwitter(string PostData, string SelectedMedia)
    {
        string tweetresp = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {


            var oauth = new OAuthInfo
            {
                AccessToken = Convert.ToString(Session["twitter_token"]),
                AccessSecret = Convert.ToString(Session["twitter_token_secret"]),
                ConsumerKey = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"]) ,
                ConsumerSecret =Convert.ToString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"]) 
            };

            var twitter = new TinyTwitter(oauth);
            List<string> li = new List<string>();
            string[] files = SelectedMedia.Split(',');
            List<string> FileList = new List<string>();
            string media = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedMedia))
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                    FileList.Add(Server.MapPath(file));


                foreach (string item in FileList)
                {
                    li.Add(GetMediaId(twitter, item));
                }
                media = string.Join(",", li);
            }
            //li.Add(GetMediaId(twitter, file1));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedMedia))
            {
                 tweetresp = twitter.UpdateStatuswithmedia(PostData, media);
            }
            else
            tweetresp = twitter.UpdateStatus(PostData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return tweetresp;
    }
```

Here is the GetMediaId method

```
        public string GetMediaId(TinyTwitter twit, string file)
    {
        byte[] files = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        string Base64File = Convert.ToBase64String(files);
        string response = twit.UpdateMedia(Base64File);
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(response);
        return Convert.ToString(j["media_id"]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would post a status update with an image using this please? It's not obvious from your code.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dave  I have updated my answer.You can use the "PostToTwitter" method to post a status update with an image or multiple images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but that doesn't even look like it would work, for example where is:

-  the method: 'GetMediaId'?
- The assembly Common
- the class Influencer

etc etc??

Comment: i have added the GwtMediaId method. the common class and the influencer class are not required. I was  using them to retrieve the tokens

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error usually means your token is not valid or your key and secret is not valid. It is also possible that it does not reach Twitter. I am in a rush to run your code, but I would like you to make sure the following two things:

1. Can you do the same thing with Twitter.com without any error?
2. Can you make a post without media using those tokens?

Comment: Actually no I am not able to make a post as well with this

Comment: It seems your tokens are not valid then. Go to your app and grab a fresh set of credentials. Identify the issues one by one and rectify them in order.